# Yii2 PJAX - MODAL RELOAD BUG

Tags: gridview, yii2, reload, pjax, kartik-v

Need a help.

In my view page I have some render block.

```
 <?= $this->render("_manageLocationsModal", ['availableLocations' => $availableLocations]);?>
```

My Modal seems like this.

```
  <div class="modal fade" style="display: none">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
       <div class="modal-content">
               <?php Pjax::begin();?>
                    <?=GridView::widget([
                            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
                            'filterModel'  => $searchModel,
                  ........
       </div>
     </div>
  </div>
```

In modal Ordering works fine, but after search the page is reloaded.

How I can fix it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use Pjax inside modal, there is something you can't control. I have an idea for your case:

- In your view, create modal with empty content, when button click, show modal and call ajax to controller, to load-grid-view, and bring response to content of modal.
- In your controller, create action load-grid-view, and renderAjax to _grid.php
- In file _grid.php, echo GridView::widget(...), and override grid filter and sort as code bellow:

  ```
  $('#<list-id>').on('beforeFilter', function (e) {

      // Call ajax with serialize() filters input and replace content in modal
      return false;
  });

  $('#<list-id>').on('click', '.pagination a, th a[data-sort]', function(e) 
  {
      var url = $(this).attr('href');
      // Call ajax with serialize() filters input and replace content in modal
      return false;      
  });
  ```

Comment: Thanks :) I will try that way too, But you know it's works, i just don't know how to close question . The problem is in activeForm, if render is in ActiveForm then pjax dont work, if I change location of code it's work successfully.